# Rofi/dmenu alternative for Windows 11 for pasting snippets from a list

Tags: windows-11, snippets

I'm looking for a tool on Windows 11, which I could use to launch some sort of a finder, search among text snippets I have previously configured and paste the selected one to where my cursor was when I opened this.

What I *don't* want is something like autohotkey replacing the typed string every time I type it. I want to be able to manually trigger a search for snippets. Any ideas where I should look to?